# Can PermissionRequiredMixin and LoginRequiredMixin be combined?

Tags: django, django-1.9

I have some users that are allowed to see a certain view.

To allow users to login and complain with a `403 Forbidden` for those users that cannot see that login, I can use the following (as explained [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#the-permission-required-decorator)):

```
@permission_required('polls.can_vote', raise_exception=True)
@login_required
def my_view(request):
    ...
```

This indeed works as expected. But all my views are class-based views. Since Django 1.9 (finally!) there are a bunch of pretty mixins for doing things that were only possible through the decorators. However...

```
class MyClassView(LoginRequiredMixin, PermissionRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    raise_exception = <???>
    permission_required = 'polls.can_vote'
    template_name = 'poll_vote.html'
```

this doesn't work. Because the `raise_exception` flag is used by both `LoginRequiredMixin` and `PermissionRequiredMixin`, I cannot set it to anything.

- if `raise_exception` is `True`, a user that is not logged in receives a `403 Forbidden` (which I do not want).
- if `raise_exception` is `False`, a user that is **not** allowed to see the view, will be redirected to the login page which, because the user is logged in, will redirect again to the page. Creating a not-at-all fancy redirect loop.

Of course I could implement my own mixin that behaves I expected, but is there any Django-way of doing this in the view itself? (not in the `urls.py`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The desired behavior is the default since 2.1, so the other answers are obsolete:

> **Changed in 2.1:** In older versions, authenticated users who lacked permissions were redirected to the login page (which resulted in a loop) instead of receiving an HTTP 403 Forbidden response. [[src](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#redirecting-unauthorized-requests-in-class-based-views)]

Comment: The question was tagged Django 1.9 because it seemed rellevant at the time. Good to know the current behaviour, so far in the future :)

Answer (score 5):

For many cases raising 403 for unauthenticated users is the expected behaviour. So yes, you need a custom mixin:

```
class LoggedInPermissionsMixin(PermissionRequiredMixin):
     def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.request.user.is_authenticated():
            return redirect_to_login(self.request.get_full_path(),
                                     self.get_login_url(), self.get_redirect_field_name())
        if not self.has_permission():
            # We could also use "return self.handle_no_permission()" here
            raise PermissionDenied(self.get_permission_denied_message())
        return super(LoggedInPermissionsMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to add a comment, but my reputation does not allow. How about the following? I feel the below is more readable?

**Updated after comments**

My reasoning is: You basically write modified `dispatch` from `LoginRequiredMixin` and just set `raise_exception = True`. `PermissionRequiredMixin` will `raise PermissionDenied` when correct permissions are not met

```
class LoggedInPermissionsMixin(PermissionRequiredMixin):
    raise_exception = True

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.request.user.is_authenticated():
            return redirect_to_login(self.request.get_full_path(),
                                     self.get_login_url(),
                                     self.get_redirect_field_name())
        return super(LoggedInPermissionsMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 3):

Simplest solution seems to be a custom view mixin.
Something like that:

```
class PermissionsMixin(PermissionRequiredMixin):
    def handle_no_permission(self):
        self.raise_exception = self.request.user.is_authenticated()
        return super(PermissionsMixin, self).handle_no_permission()
```

Or, just use `PermissionRequiredMixin` as usual and put this `handle_no_premission` to every CBV.